# cannot resolve symbol 'toolbar' r.id.toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar, slidingdrawer

i'm trying to create a sliding drawer.  I spent forever getting my imports to match my code, in terms of getSupportActionBar vs getActionBar etc., I suspect the issue is somewhere in the activity_main.xml but I'm at a loss for what to put there.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
             if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();
            }

        else {
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding. add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "About"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Android"));
        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);


        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        assert getActionBar() != null;
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //set title
        setTitle(listSliding.get(0).getTitle());
        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //set title
                setTitle(listSliding.get(position).getTitle());
                //item selected
                listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //close menu
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.action_logout) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context="me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: your toolbar has id `drawer_layout`. Why are you using `toolbar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` for your main_layout root tag? That's not what android says.

You should use that Toolbar just for using Toolbar with your activity.

See: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

That won't work at all.

**Use it like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd rather to use `CoordinatorLayout` with AppCompat or this Toolbar implementation too.

Also,

```
//display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Here you were using `toolbar` as that `Toolbar` id.

Use it like this in your xml:

```
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
```

Above code should work now.Also, you've many not used in your imports like:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and etc.

Read the docs please.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
R.id.drawer_layout
```

Instead of

```
R.id.toolbar
```

Comment: It warns me "The id R.id.drawer_layout has already been looked up in this method.  Possible copy & paste error?"
Then when I run it I get:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.paxana.alerta/me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Comment: I tried changing the xml tag to v4.widget.drawerlayout instead of toolbar but no dice

Comment: I think your XML is a bit messed up. If you copied it from somewhere overwrite it with a fresh copy. The id  for your toolbar is drawer_layout. It does not sound right.